# Маленький скрипт Shell Bash

Tags: bash, unix, shell

Задачка такова

Написать программу, выводящую через определенный интервал времени информацию о пользователях в системе: кто вошел, кто вышел.

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ true ]; do
    clear
    date
    who
    sleep 5
done
```

Результат работы программы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему не выводится пользователь?(дату и время вывожу для проверки работы самой программы)
Запуск с Винды через Git Bash

Comment: приложите результат работы в вопрос, а не скриншотом на непонятном сайте

Comment: @AlexeyTen Подправлено

Comment: А who разве в винде работает?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Этого я не знаю. Но команда подсвечивается как активная( в отличие  от last) .Who брал из методички. Возможно , есть какой-то другой вариант?

Comment: @Vs_De_S, маленький совет -- перед тем как писать скрипт, выполняйте все команды из него ручками в терминале

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я помню, что бы через скрипт получит текущее имя пользователя, нужно использовать не `who`, а `whoami`.

Так же можно использовать переменную `$USER`.

Comment: whoami оказалась неактивной у меня почему -то ..$USER тоже ничего не вывел

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbRwu.jpg

Comment: можете пожалуйста отправить прикрепить сам код скрипта полностью? Потому что я делал ровно так же как Вы написали, но почему то не выводится. :(